# Drupal: how to make uploaded images stored in different folders based on content type?

Tags: drupal, file-upload, directory

I am using Drupal 7.

I have a few content types and each type allows image upload. I am hoping to store uploaded images in different folders for each content type.

Does Drupal support this? I did a lot of online search but am unable to find a way or module for doing this. Hope I did not miss anything.

Thanks for any input.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module [File (Field) Paths](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) is what you are looking for: it let you change the upload path for each field. You can also add tokens.

[image: File Field Paths GUI]

Comment: Thanks soooo much. This is exactly what I wanted. After install, the images are saved in correct folders, but I always got the following error. Any idea?


    Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference in filefield_paths_filefield_paths_process_file() (line 66 of E:\Tools\drupal-rfic\sites\all\modules\contrib\filefield_paths\modules\filefield_paths.inc).
    Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$original in file_field_update() (line 265 of E:\Tools\drupal-rfic\modules\file\file.field.inc).

Comment: I just found out that these two issues were fixed in 2012-Aug-10 development version. Cheers!